# Can i change the initially determined max value of the control variable after the loop starts?

Tags: matlab

In the code maximum value of `u` is 1(because length of `x` is 1) at the time of the start of the loop. After calling `newftn()`, length of `x` changes. I want my loop to follow the new length of `x` but it terminates after 1 cycle (i.e. the initial length of `x`). Please suggest how can I achieve the desired behavior.

```
x(1) = 1; 
for u = 1:length(x)
    p = 3;
    newftn(); 
end  
function newftn()
    c = [4,5];
    x = horzcat(x,c); 
end
```

Comment: The loop you intend to write will have now end. This smells like an XY problem, what do you actually want to do?

Comment: I believe this to be too simplified. There may be a function which does what you need already. If you clarify the post you may be able to get a better answer. (By the way, not answering other peoples questions will not get you anywhere. I see this a lot on SO. People write a question and then sit back down and wait for answers. I have never seen one of these questions being solved).

Comment: @Patrik....yes i think I over simplified it...but I've solved it anyway. I wanted to share my solution but again it won't relate directly to the question I've asked as the question it too much simplified. Thanks for ur suggestion anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You cannot avoid this when using a `for` loop because once no. of iterations of a `for` are decided, it cannot be changed later. You can achieve your desired behavior using a `while` loop.
2. It is a better practice to [pre-allocate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) memory for a vector instead of growing its size in a loop. e.g. `x= zeros(1,n)` and then replacing the values.
3. What you're trying to do here seems like an infinite loop requiring an infinite size of memory. I'm sure this is not what you want! You need to modify your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this with a `while` loop instead:

```
x(1) = 1;
c = [4 , 5];
u = 0;
while u < length(x)
    u = u + 1;
    p = 3;
    x = horzcat(x,c);
end
```

Comment: you are welcome @TariqIslam, but if you take a look at `u`, it follows the order of 1, 2, 3, and so on. Generally you can always replace a for loop with a while loop.